# Change input base in shell script with dc?

Tags: shell, dc

I'm trying to change the input and the output base using dc in a shell script. I'm having trouble writing down the exact command. I do not have BASH.

I've tried variations on this: (input numb) 2i 10o p | dc

Comment: @shellter: How is bash relevant?

Comment: @shellter: Thanks.  Regardless of my answer, the [tag:shell] tag is probably both appropriate and enough to get responses (it's why I saw it).  It seems inappropriate to use [tag:bash] when both the question and the solution are equally applicable to, say, [tag:tcsh], or [tag:ksh], or [tag:zsh].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `dc` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dc) uses the term "radix", not "base"; that might help you search for information.

You have to set the input radix *before* giving it an input number.  For example:

```
echo 100 2i p | dc
```

prints `100` (decimal) because the radix was still set to the default 10 (decimal) when `dc` saw the input value `100`.

Try this:

```
echo 16i DEADBEEF 10o p 2o p | dc # but see below
```

The output is:

```
DEADBEEF
11011110101011011011111011101111
```

Note that `dc` seems to require upper case for the hex digits `A` .. `F`.  And you have to be careful with radix specifications; after you've done `16i` to set input to hexadecimal, `10i` interprets `10` as a hexadecimal number and sets the input radix to 16 (and `16i` tries to set it to 0x16 or 22, which is illegal).

In fact, I see I ran into that problem myself.  I meant to set the output radix to 16.  I should have written `Ao p 2o p` rather than `10o p 2o p`.  I'll leave it as it is to illustrate the issue.